eBPF: tc vs. cgroup skb vs. xt_bpf routes?
What is the difference between attaching an eBPF function to a TC route, an cgroup skb, or an xt_bpf route?
I'm attempting to access all network packet traffic from an Android device which doesn't have TC as an available route.
However there are routes available like "cgroupskb/ingress/stats" and "skfilter/ingress/xtbpf" (and their equivalents for egress).
I believe TC route shows all traffic, how about the other two? Which one would I use if I want to capture all incoming or outgoing packet traffic?
I tried attaching a tracepoint to cgroupskb/ingress/stats but it didn't seem to be showing all traffic (I made a TCP packet example and those were did not seem to be added to the map).
